# Passing data from a function inside controller to a function inside a directive in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function inside an angular controller that calls a factory to request data from an API and calls a function inside a directive, This is working fine. But the retrieved data needs to be passed into the function inside the directive and I can't seem to get anything besides 'undefined' as the data inside the directive function, whereas in the controller function it's working fine. I have used .then() to chain the data retrieval and the directive function call to make them run consecutively, but it doesn't help, I can't seem to pass anything defined inside the function in controller to the directive function.

My code looks like this:

Controller

```
angular.module('myControllerModule', ['getData'])
.controller('myViewController', function($scope, getDataFactory){

    // Mapping the directive function to controller
    $scope.setDirectiveFn = function(directiveFn){
        $scope.directiveFn = directiveFn;
    };

    // the function used for the factory and directive function call 
    $scope.search = function(){
        $scope.RetreivedData = getDataFactory.getTheData()
           .then(function successCallback(response){
                $scope.data = response.data; // This is not passed
            }).then($scope.directiveFn())
    };
});
```

Factory

```
angular.module('getData',[])
.factory('getDataFactory', function($http){
    return{
        getTheData: function() {
            return $http({
                url: 'url/to/API/endpoint',
                method: 'GET'
            })
        },
    }
});
```

Directive

```
angular.module('myChartModule')
.directive('chart', function (){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            setFn: '&',
        },
        controller: 'myViewControllerr',
        templateurl: '/path/to/my/template/file.html',
        link: function link(scope, element, attr){

          scope.drawChart = function(){    
            var chartData = scope.data; //undefined
            console.log(chartData);
          };
          // mapping the directive funtion to contorller
          scope.setFn({theDirFn: scope.drawPSA});
        }
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<chart data= 'data' set-fn="setDirectiveFn(theDirFn)"></chart>
```

I can't seem to find a way to solve this, and more importantly, I'm not really sure where the problem lies...

Comment: its seems you created isolated scope in directive and if you want to use ctrl scope then use ctrl that forth parameter in link function

Comment: If you wise you can set a watcher in directive to set `data` is populated or not

Comment: @JayantPatil Not sure what you mean? There is already 2-way binding with the `$scope.data` between the controller and the directive and the directive function is mapped to a function inside the controller. If I define data outside of the `$scope.search` function in the controller I can pass it to `drawChart` function in the directive. But if I define (or change the value) of the `data` in the search function it's not coming through.

Comment: @M.K by adding scope: in directive it isolate ctrl scope means it create new scope for directive so i suggest to remove that from directive then you will get ctrl scope link scope param.

Comment: @Satpal Putting a `scope.$watch` function into the directive link function, outside of the `drawChart()` function lead to and error: `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$rootScope/infdig?`, which, as I understand it, means that the app went into an infinite loop of digest cycles. It did print a whole lot of the actual data with it, which makes me think that this might be a problem with the promise/asynchrony. Still no clear solution in sight I'm afraid...

Comment: The `myViewController` is *inside* the directive? What is outside the directive? What is `scope.draPSA`?

Comment: @georgeawg Nope, the controller is separate and controls a view with multiple directives in it. The `scope.drawChart` function is inside the directive link function. (It's really just a wrapper for D3 visualization script that needs the data from the API, that can be called from the controller)

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this. It was a problem with the promise chain. I wrapped the directive function call inside the controller `search` function to an anonymous function And now the data is coming through.

```
$scope.search = function(){
    $scope.RetreivedData = getDataFactory.getTheData()
        .then(function successCallback(response){
            $scope.data = response.data;
         })
         .then(function(data){
            $scope.directiveFn($scope.data)
         })
};
```